# Laravel, filtre by two dates. Got an Error

Tags: laravel

**Edit**

I'm trying to get data by two times, so i wrote this code in Laravel.

**Controller**

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
 public function manage() 
{
      $date1 = date("d-m-Y", Input::get('date1'));
     $date2 = date("d-m-Y", Input::get('date2'));
     $filtre = DB::table('rinvoices')->whereBetween('updated_at', [$date1, $date2])->get();
```

**Blade file**

```html
  <input type="date" name="date1" id="date1" value="01-11-2018"/>
   <input type="date" name="date2" id="date2" value="05-11-2018" />
  <table>
    <tbody>
       @foreach($filtre as $f)
        <tr>
         <td>{{$f->coderinvoice}} </td>
        </tr>
       @endforeach
      </tbody>
   </table>
```

Error:

> InvalidArgumentException. Illegal operator and value combination.

Comment: Have you dumped the variables $date1 and $date2 to check that they are set and that they are set in the correct format for comparison? Does $filtre return results when the where conditions are in place?

Comment: Hello, please check out my eddited post, dd($date1) returns 01-01-1970 and not the value of date in input..

Comment: You have a typo. `id=date2"` You're missing a quote.

Comment: Thank u, but still returns 01-01-1970..

Comment: 01-01-1970 is the start of Unix time so that means that $date1 is not being set. Can you dd(Input::all()); please?

Comment: @user10341554 result empty

Comment: Okay, so there's your problem! Are you inputting this using a form? Are you submitting it using a http POST request? If so, I have submitted an answer.

Comment: @user10341554 no i'm not, i just want to change the value of the variable from blade, to get filtre data by date

Comment: But if you are not sending this via a HTTP request to the controller, how will it retrieve these values? If these are hardcoded values you should set them in your controller.

Answer (score 2):

Use double `where` clause:

```php
$filtre = DB::table('rinvoices')
    ->where('updated_at','>',$date1) 
    ->where('updated_at','<',$date2) 
    ->get();
```

Or you can use simply `whereBetween`:

```php
$filtre = DB::table('rinvoices')
    ->whereBetween('updated_at', [$date1, $date2])
    ->get();
```

Comment: Hello, please check out my eddited post, dd($date1) returns 01-01-1970 and not the value of date in input..

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the request data, set it to variables and set the correct format (I use Carbon by using Carbon\Carbon). Your problem was that your date variables were not set so they were defaulting to start Unix time. If you gather the request data from a POST form request, you should be able to access this now.

```
public function manage(Request $request) 
{

     $date1 = ($request->date1)->format('Y-m-d');
     $date2 = ($request->date2)->format('Y-m-d');

     $filtre = DB::table('rinvoices')->whereBetween('updated_at', [$date1, $date2])->get();
}
```

However, if you want to create hard-coded dates, it is best to add these in your controller.

```
public function manage() 
{

     $date1 = "2018-11-01";
     $date2 = "2018-11-05";

     $filtre = DB::table('rinvoices')->whereBetween('updated_at', [$date1, $date2])->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You was wrong way when use [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function, then second argument is timestamp. 
This should work:

```
$date1 = date("d-m-Y", strtotime(Input::get('date1')));
$date2 = date("d-m-Y", strtotime(Input::get('date2')));
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's default DATE format is YYYY-MM-DD.

The date string should be transform into "Y-m-d" before query.

```php
$date1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(Input::get('date1'), 'd-m-Y'));
$date2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(Input::get('date2'), 'd-m-Y'));

$filtre = DB::table('rinvoices')
    ->whereBetween('updated_at', [$date1, $date2])
    ->get();
```